# Change the template accoding to publisher selection in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have two selectors: one for publisher and one for template. If I select publisher id=2, then in second selector (which is for template) it only shows the values according to that publisher. In template table there is a `publisher_id` .

```html
<v-flex>
      @can('publish')
      @if (sizeof($publishers) > 1)
      <v-text-field type="hidden" style="display: none" v-model="publishers" name="publishers"></v-text-field>
      <v-select label="Publishers" item-text="name" item-value="id" v-model="publishers" :rules="[rules.required]" chips persistent-hint>
      </v-select>
           <div class="text-danger">
               {{ $errors->first('publisher_id') }}
           </div>
           <v-text-field type="hidden" name="publisher_id" 
      </v-text-field>               
  </v-flex>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter templates based on the currently selected publisher:

```html
<v-flex>
   @can('publish')
   @if (sizeof($publishers) > 1)
   <input type="hidden" :value="selectedPublisher" name="publishers">
   <v-select label="Publishers" item-text="name" item-value="id" v-model="selectedPublisher" :rules="[rules.required]" chips persistent-hint>
   </v-select>
        <div class="text-danger">
            {{ $errors->first('publisher_id') }}
        </div>
        <v-select label="Templates" item-text="name" item-value="id" v-model="templates" :items="listTemplates.filter(tpl => selectedPublisher === tpl.publisher_id)" :rules="[rules.required]" chips persistent-hint/>
        <input type="hidden" name="publisher_id">
   </v-text-field>               
</v-flex>
```